# Creating Multiple Admin Widget Page with Calling One Sidebar

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

Does anyone know how to create multiple admin widget pages with calling specific sidebars?

In Detail,

I have a custom post type called Groups and I am creating new admin pages in the back end.

I added a submenu to Groups called Widgets. I created a sidebar for Groups and I want to add this sidebar to the Groups widget page.

So, it is just like usual admin widget page but with only one sidebar.

So far,

```
$post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
$retrieved_widgets = retrieve_widgets();
foreach ($retrieved_widgets as $key => $value) {
   if ( $key !== "groups-sidebar" ) {
    unset($retrieved_widgets[$key]);
    }
}

$wp_registered_sidebars = $retrieved_widgets;
//print_r($wp_registered_sidebars);
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/widgets.php');
```

This code adds only the groups sidebar to the Groups Widget page. But I have some errors such as

```
Notice: Undefined index: class in D:\wp-admin\widgets.php on line 369
```

So I am guessing something is missing or not configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code deletes keys from widgets. One of those keys is named 'class'. When WordPress looks for the 'class' key it is missing and PHP reports that.

I think you want this:

```
$groups_sidebars = array();

foreach ( retrieve_widgets() as $widget ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'groups-sidebar', $widget ) )
        $groups_sidebars[] = $widget;
}

$wp_registered_sidebars = $groups_sidebars;
```